# Flutter : Getting appcenter:verifyReleaseResources Error When Trying to Build in AppCenter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

**I have followed this blog to build my app on AppCenter**

**Exactly did the same process**

https://medium.com/@maite.daluz11/deploy-flutter-apps-using-appcenter-ec28e8d940bf

**APPCENTER BUILD OUTPUT IS SHOWING**

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

> Android resource linking failed

     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207/core 1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.



     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.



BUILD FAILED in 2m 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          137.7s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android/settings_aar.gradle`...                        1ms
✓ `android/settings_aar.gradle` created successfully.
Building plugin appcenter...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                        35.1s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin appcenter_analytics...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                         2.7s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin appcenter_crashes...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                         2.4s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                        20.9s
Gradle 5.4.1
Resolved com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 in :classpath 
Resolved androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 in :releaseRuntimeClasspath 
Resolved io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4 in :releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 in :releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 in :releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.5.0 in :lintClassPath 

/Users/runner/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/lifecycle/FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:8: error: package androidx.lifecycle does not exist
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
                         ^
/Users/runner/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/lifecycle/FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
  public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
                ^
  symbol:   class Lifecycle
  location: class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

BUILD FAILED in 18s

The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.
```

**My android/app/build.gradle is:**

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 29

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.flutter_tls_identity"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.0.0'
   implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
   implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
}
```

**My android/build.gradle is:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My android/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh is:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Place this script in project/android/app/

cd ..

#fail if any command fails
set -e
#debug log
set -x

cd ..
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter channel stable
flutter doctor

echo "Installed flutter to `pwd`/flutter"

#build APK
#if you get "Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'." error, uncomment next two lines
#flutter build apk --debug
#flutter build apk --profile
flutter build apk --release

#if you need build bundle (AAB) in addition to your APK, uncomment line below and last line of this script.
#flutter build appbundle --release --build-number $APPCENTER_BUILD_ID

#copy the APK where AppCenter will find it
mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/apk/; mv build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk $_

#copy the AAB where AppCenter will find it
#mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/bundle/; mv build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab $_
```

**My gradle.properties is**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

**My pubspec.yaml dependencies is**

```
dependencies:          
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter       
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
      path_provider:
      image_picker:
      appcenter:
      appcenter_analytics:
      appcenter_crashes:
```

**My gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to the error is;**

**1 -** Open your **android/build.gradle** & add the following code under your last **subprojects**

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28 --> This is the version in my android/app/build.gradle 
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2 -** **Right click** to the **android[flutter_app_name]** folder & go to Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio

**3 -** Under your **Project** folder open **android** -> **android [appcenter]** -> **build.gradle** & make sure the following **Versions** are same with the one's in your **android/app/build.gradle**

1. compileSdkVersion
2. buildToolsVersion
3. minSdkVersion
4. targetSdkVersion

```
group 'com.aloisdeniel.flutter.appcenter'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28 --> Make sure this version is same with the one in your android/app/build.gradle 
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' --> Make sure this version is same with the one in your android/app/build.gradle 

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21 --> Make sure this version is same with the one in your android/app/build.gradle 
        targetSdkVersion 28 --> Make sure this version is same with the one in your android/app/build.gradle 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    dependencies {
        def appCenterSdkVersion = '1.10.0'
        implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    }
}
```

**4 -** Do the same process for the **android [appcenter_analytics]** & **android [appcenter_crashes]**.

**5 -** In terminal type **flutter clean** and after it finishes type **flutter build apk**.